# With psycopg2 how to avoid using the connection context manager

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

With psycopg2, connection and querying the database works like so

```
conn = psycopg2.connect('connection string')
with conn:
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity") #simple query 
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
       print (row)
```

After trial and error, I found out that `with conn` is absolutely necessary or you will get many unexplained locks.

My question is: is there a way to setup the connection to avoid the need to use it?

Comment: you don't need to use a context manager it just makes it so you don't have to remember to close the connection when you are done using it, it's there to make your job easier

Comment: If you call `conn.close()` to close the connection at the end of your operation, you can ignore the context manager.

Comment: The code is ok, what error did you get?

Comment: Do you need to close the cursor as well, like cur.close() or is this done by the context manager?

Answer (score 10):

From https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html,

> **Warning**
>   Unlike file objects or other resources, exiting the connection’s *with*
>   block **doesn’t close the connection**, but only the transaction
>   associated to it. If you want to make sure the connection is closed
>   after a certain point, you should still use a try-catch block:

```
   conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
   try:  
     # connection usage 
   finally:  
     conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this the reason. Do you think that is what you meant: https://codeshare.io/MNWvlp

Answer (score 3):

In `psycopg`, the Context manager has been implemented in such a way that the with statement will only terminate the transaction and not close the connection for you. The connection needs to be closed by you separately.

In case of an error with your transaction, you have the option to rollback and raise the error.

One way to do this is to write the connection closing logic yourself.

```
def with_connection(func):
    """
    Function decorator for passing connections
    """
    def connection(*args, **kwargs):
        # Here, you may even use a connection pool
        conn = psycopg.connect(DSN)
        try:
            rv = func(conn, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            conn.rollback()
            raise e
        else:
            # Can decide to see if you need to commit the transaction or not
            conn.commit()
        finally:
            conn.close()
        return rv
    return connection

@with_connection
def run_sql(conn, arg1):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(SQL, (arg1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Version 2.5, psycopg2 should support the `with` statement like you expect it to behave.
[Docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#with-statement)

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)

with conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute(SQL1)

with conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute(SQL2)

conn.close()
```

Comment: If you using context manager like `with` one - you don't need to use `conn.close`

Comment: @r1v3n 'with connection' in psycopg2 only closes the transaction, not the connection. 'with connection' in psycopg3 also closes the connection. To just close the transaction in psycopg3, we can use 'with connection.transcation()'. See https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/from_pg2.html#with-connection