# How to implement a context manager for connections/cursors in Python?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I've been refactoring my SQL queries in Python into functions (I use psycopg2). Before I had it all in try-except-finally blocks, and it was a bit messy to add multiple connections, however I am not quite sure how to implement a context-manager to handle the connections and cursors.

1. First version, yields connection and cursor separately.

```
@contextmanager
def get_connection(**DB_CONNECTION):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(**DB_CONNECTION)
    try:
        yield connection
    except Exception as err:
        connection.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        if (connection):
            connection.close()

@contextmanager
def get_cursor(connection):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        yield cursor
    finally:
        cursor.close()

with get_connection(**DB_CONNECTION) as conn, get_cursor(conn) as cursor:
    random_test_query()
    insert_test_query()
```

2. Second version, yields both connection and cursor.

```
@contextmanager
def sql_connection(**DB_CONNECTION):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(**DB_CONNECTION)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        yield connection,cursor
    except Exception as err:
        connection.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        if (connection):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()

with sql_connection() as (conn, cursor):
    random_test_query()
    insert_test_query()
```

My questions are:

1. Is there any difference between the first and the second version? Which one is preferable?
2. If I'm using a context manager, do I still need to include a `connection.commit()`? From the [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html), I understand that no longer necessary. Can I remove them?

Comment: You do know, don't you, that since version 2.5, psycopg2 cursors are already context managers themselves?  So are connections, but those do connection rollback or commit at context exit, rather than connection closure.

Comment: [Relevant docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#with-statement)

Comment: @JohnBollinger I see, what if I want to reuse code and not declare a new "conn = psycopg2.connect(***)" every time? How should I rewrite this code? Something like this: [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67920095/19650159) , [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64833663/19650159) or [Example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72630254/19650159) ?

Comment: My point is that you do not need to wrap your cursors in separate context managers.  And to be absolutely clear, I recommend not doing so.  The connections are a separate question, but code reuse for creating connections seems to me largely separate from the context manager issue.

Comment: As a separate matter, I note that the context manager examples presented in this question will exhibit the surprising behavior of *always* rolling back transactions at context exit (as opposed to only when the context is exited via exception, as appears to be the intent).  This is because closing a psycopg2 connection has that effect on any open transaction, and you do not explicitly `commit()` in the context manager code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You're right, my definition of context managers was totally wrong. At the end I used the WITH statement as suggested in docs.

Comment: Thanks for the update @SamSepiol.  You should consider writing a self-answer explaining that in more detail.